# Is it possible to make Ubuntu look like the login screen?

Tags: appearance

I'm particularily fond of the way the login screen looks (with the glassy appearance on the login window & the top bar) - and was wondering if it's possible to change the appearance to match it?

Answer (score 0):

Try Unity Tweaks, available in the Ubuntu Apps Store. You might not be able to change some things that you want, but there will another thing you can change to make it more like you want (that's the cool thing about linux).